# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable

Tags: java, itext

I'm using itextpdf-5.5.6.jar and bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar, and getting a exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

itext POM marks bouncycastle as optional

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
<artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
<version>1.49</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
<optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

so you must include bouncycastle in your project POM to make sure it's available.

Note that bouncycastle 1.49 is [recommended](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.6) for itext5.5.6

Answer (score 0):

Please download the bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar (for JDK 1.5 - 1.7) file from below given link and add in your project to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable exception.

http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

find the appropriate jar file from the above link according to your JDK version.

**Another way :**

You can check the dependency of itext 5.5 at the following URL.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.0

According to this page, corresponding version of bouncycastle for itext 5.5 is 1.49. I read on a page somewhere on internet that bouncycastle is heavily changing and it is often hard to find corresponding version of bouncycastle for a specific version of itext.

Comment: Well, it's not hard to find. If you use Maven, and don't use another version of BouncyCastle anywhere else in your project, then It Just Works. If you for some reason don't want to use Maven, then yes you have to take responsibility for the dependencies yourself.